# ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'Nginx Full'

Tags: nginx

I have installed latest version of nginx.It is is installed succefully.

But getting error while typing the below command.

sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'

## Error:ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'Nginx Full'

sudo ufw app list

showing only

Available applications:

## OpenSSH

How to add the application.
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH

I have installed two times nginx server

Error:ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'Nginx Full'

Comment: on which system are you trying to configure this? (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04 - Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 42):

**Ubuntu (18.04)**

You can see which apps are available by running this command:

```
ufw app list
```

Ports:
HTTP - 80
HTTPS - 443

Simple way to add them to UFW:

```
ufw allow 80,443/tcp
```

If you are wanting to accomplish this via application you will need to create the application ini file within /etc/ufw/applications.d

Example:

```
vi /etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx.ini
```

Place this inside file

```
[Nginx HTTP]
title=Web Server 
description=Enable NGINX HTTP traffic
ports=80/tcp

[Nginx HTTPS] \
title=Web Server (HTTPS) \
description=Enable NGINX HTTPS traffic
ports=443/tcp

[Nginx Full]
title=Web Server (HTTP,HTTPS)
description=Enable NGINX HTTP and HTTPS traffic
ports=80,443/tcp
```

Then type this commands

```
ufw app update nginx

ufw app info 'Nginx HTTP'

ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.. turned out Nginx was not installed due to some reason.
So it showed only OpenSSH by doing

```
sudo ufw app list
```

I got to this when I tried to uninstall Nginx using the command

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx
```

The output showed something like this:
Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed

Now you have to try installing Nginx again using commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
sudo ufw app list
```

now the options will be available
// Check to see
Available applications:
Nginx Full
Nginx HTTP
Nginx HTTPS
OpenSSH

Now allow HTTP port using the command:

```
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
```

And finally run this command:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Now hit the URL in browser it will show Nginx default page.

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'OpenSSH', Then install first ssh by given command

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

> After installing package add the OpenSSH allow

```
sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
sudo ufw status
```

> Tested

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me after installing using the [official site's instructions for Ubuntu](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu)

Simply install as this (after removing if already installed)

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx
sudo apt install nginx
```